# R save excel file with user input as name

Tags: excel, matlab

So I am having a problem uploading files from RStudio to Excel for MATLAB processing.
I had this problem before with formulas not being populated, so I made a script to open, save, and close the Excel file which then worked fine for populating the formulas and loading the numerical values back into RStudio. However I can not figure out how to open multiple .csv files that have changing names depending on our sample ID.

Heres my script that I tried to have open up multiple files:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\PCRdata\*.csv")
## Also tried Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\PCRdata\"& "*.csv")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Your Excel Spreadsheet was Updated, Open these files in Matlab"
WScript.Quit
```

However the script doesnt like the * to call upon all files, is there another way I can do this? or a better way to have RStudios come out with data that is usable to matlab.

MATLAB Error:

```
Error using netest/testingBrowseButton_Callback (line 63)
Cannot concatenate the table variables 'AKAP8L' and 'ARAF', because their types are double and cell.

Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

Answer (score 0):

Well did some digging on the website and found an alternative post that used a script to change change xls to xslx so I just made it so it went from csv to csv. Hope this helps anyone else that had this problem.

```
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
app.Visible = False
app.DisplayAlerts = False
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\PCRdata").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "csv" Then
    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)

    wb.Save
    wb.Close True
  End if
Next

app.Quit
Set f = Nothing
Set app = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
wScript.Quit
```